# how to change explicitly encoding in Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I'am using `Jackson` to map a json file to java object and there is an element in the json file that contains the character `É`,I got the error below:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x41
 at [Source: (File); line: 129, column: 35]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
```

So, is there a way to change the default encoding of the `objectMapper` from `utf-8` to `utf-32`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson automatically detects encoding UTF-32 UTF-16 UTF-8 from the header change the server to send the encoding with `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-32` alternatively, if it's a file it detects it from it first bytes https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-3

your problem is that the encoding is not done in UTF-32 in this case you need to sanitize it like this if your encoding is ISO-8859-1

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("tourneeCollecteRawOutputCalculIndicateur.json");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharset.ISO_8859_1);
TourneeCollecteRawOutput tourneeCollecteRawOutput = mapper.readValue(in, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, TourneeCollecteRawOutput.class));
```

Comment: I can not use Reader object, i get the json file when i call a microservice

Comment: then check the header of the microservice, does it send the content 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-32'

Comment: Correct the encoding from the microservice

Comment: i do not have access to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204948/discussion-between-karim-and-abdelmouheimen).