# How to accept accents in ObjectMapper

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, objectmapper

I have a springboot application that is subscribed to a Google Cloud PubSub topic. The connection is correct and I am able to read messages and do the necessary processing when I receive a message to the topic.

The problem is when a special character arrives in said topic, such as ''á","é","í","ó","ú". That is, characters in ISO 8859-1 format. At that moment, in the traces I get this error:

`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x4e`

This is my custom object mapper:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyCustomObjectMapper configure() {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        return new MyCustomObjectMapper(mapper);
    }

}
```

This is a test message received on the topic:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "data": "{  \"myText\": \"áéíóú\"}"
        }
    ]
}
```

How could I accept messages with these special characters?

Comment: DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES has nothiing to do with character encoding.  Also, I believe that Jackson only uses UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change explicitly encoding in Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502006/how-to-change-explicitly-encoding-in-jackson)

Comment: Correct, that property has nothing to do with the encoding, but in my case it was also necessary that it be present. So, if it only accepts UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32, how can I use accents or special characters? 
Your second message it doesn't answer my question. I need to have something in the ObjectMapper bean, in that bean I don't have the input text yet

Comment: The JSON specification requires text be [encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-8.1). ISO 8859-1 is not a valid encoding for JSON. You should change the program that generated the JSON to conform to the JSON specification.

Comment: @ChinHuang that looks like an actual answer can you post it as one?